# How the directory structure for SpringBoot MongoDB CrudRepositoryCustom Implementation should be organized?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, directory

I have created a simple maven project using SpringBoot and MongoDB. I have two repository implementations i.e. *StudentRepository* and  *StudentRepositoryCustom*. *StudentRepository* extends in built *MongoRepository* and the custom repository. The custom repository methods are implemented in *StudentRepositoryImpl*. The applications runs without errors when I put **StudentRepository**, **StudentRepositoryCustom** and **StudentRepositoryImpl** in same package i.e. **com.aman.springboot.repository**. But the application throws error when the implementation class is moved to some other package let's say **com.aman.springboot.impl**.

What am I doing wrong ?

Here's the main class:

```
package com.aman.springboot.client;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.aman.springboot") 
public class ApplicationLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StudentController.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here's RestController class:

```
package com.aman.springboot.controller;

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.aman.springboot.repository")
@RequestMapping(value = "/student")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getStudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public StudentRepo getStudent(@RequestParam(required = true) int id) {
        return studentRepository.findStudentById(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/removeStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void removeStudent(@RequestBody(required = true) StudentRepo 
        studentRepo) {
        studentRepository.deleteStudent(studentRepo);
    }
}
```

Here's StudentRepository:

```
package com.aman.springboot.repository;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends MongoRepository<StudentRepo, 
    String>, StudentRepositoryCustom {      
    public StudentRepo findStudentById(int id);
}
```

Here's StudentRepositoryCustom:

```
package com.aman.springboot.repository;

public interface StudentRepositoryCustom {
    public void deleteStudent(StudentRepo studentRepo);
}
```

Here's StudentRepositoryImpl:

```
package com.aman.springboot.impl;

@Service
public class StudentRepositoryImpl implements StudentRepositoryCustom{

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepo student;

    @Override
    public void deleteStudent(StudentRepo studentRepo) {
        mongoTemplate.remove(studentRepo);
    }
}
```

As you can see both interfaces or repositories are in same package but the implementation class for StudentRepositoryCustom interface is in different package. In this case the application throws error while deploying:

Here's the stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'studentController': Unsatisfied dependency 
expressed through field 'studentRepository'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
with name 'studentRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested 
exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No 
property deleteStudent found for type StudentRepo!  at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation. 
AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject 
(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586) 
~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject 
(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]      
at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation. 
AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues 
(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372) ~[spring-beans- 
5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]    at 
.
.
.
.
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) 
[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]   at 
com.aman.springboot.client.ApplicationLauncher.main 
(ApplicationLauncher.java:17) [classes/:na] 

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'studentRepository': Invocation of init method 
failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 
deleteStudent found for type StudentRepo!   at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support. 
AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean 
(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans- 
5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]    at 
.
.
.
.
tializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans- 
5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

The application works fine if I move the StudentRepositoryImpl class to package in which the repositories are i.e. **com.aman.springboot.repository**.

Any help would be appreciated !!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by refactoring the package structure for custom repository and its implementation class. What I understand from the problem is Spring looks for implemented classes for repositories in child packages.
For example, if repository is defined in **com.foo.repo**, it's implementing class should be in **com.foo.repo.impl**.
The repositories should be defined in top level packages and the implementing class should be in same package or it's child package.